# How to copy word without selection in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I looked into this page: http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyWithoutSelection.

I copied the exactly same code to my .emacs. Somehow, only the copy-line and copy-paragraph work. But what I really want is copy-word. Every time I ran copy-word, I got an error like: "wrong type argument: integerp, nil". The weird thing is the only difference between copy-word and copy-line is copy-thing `backward-word`forward-word arg instead of `beginning-of-line and`end-of-line, and all of them are build-in. I was wondering why the copy-line works while the copy-word doesn't.

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Add `(setq debug-on-error t)` to your .emacs and try again.  The code from the wiki works fine for me (Emacs 24.2).

Comment: I tested on 21.2 in VMS and 24.2 in Win7. But I still get same error. The difference is I can see the details of the error.
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument integerp nil)
  forward-word(nil)
  funcall(forward-word nil)
  get-point(forward-word nil)
...
Seems there is something wrong with forward-word

Comment: Try cut/paste code into an Emacs w/out your .emacs (`emacs -q`) and see if the problem still happens.  If it doesn't, then there's something in your .emacs that messes it up.